# How to count in relational algebra without aggregate functions?

Tags: relational-algebra

> Find the user who has liked the most posts. Report the user’s id, name
> and email, and the id of the posts they have liked. If there is a tie,
> report them all.

The schema:

```
User(uid, name, website, about, email, phone, photo)

Likes(liker, pid, when)

Likes[liker]  is contained in  User[uid]
```

I think I need a "function" NumberOfLikes or similar where I can do something like:

[image]

We aren't allowed to use aggregate functions in this exercise. I assume the way to count in RA is by performing some sort of cross product black magic, but I don't know how.

Help?

Comment: "We aren't allowed to use aggregate functions in this exercise. " then you can't answer it, as asked; "some sort of cross product black magic" is not a thing. I assume 'aggregate functions' means the 5 operations listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Aggregation -- which includes `count`.

Comment: Or does the question provide more information? For example that there's a fixed number of distinct `User`s? BTW 'How to count in relational algebra' and/or aggregate functions in RA is a FAQ on StackOverflow. I understand why you don't want to ask over there, but you might find answers.

Comment: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)